# Limit Literal to integer type (XML/RDF)

Tags: xml, rdf, rdfs

How can we limit the Literal type:

```
<rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Literal"/>
```

To just integers (using XML/RDF notation)?

I tried:

```
<rdfs:range rdf:int/>
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: You'll need to be more specific.  What are you trying to do?  You can specify `xsd:int` as the range of a property, if that's what you mean.  If you're querying with SPARQL, you can filter out non-integer values.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I want to define a property and specify the range. I can add more code if it helps. (Yes, I will use SPARQL but SPARQL inly does queries, it doesn't forbid someone to enter non-integer values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the range on a property. The integer is defined in XMLSchema.
For instance:

```
<rdf:Property rdf:ID="testRelation">
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer"/>       
</rdf:Property>
```

Note that this is not a true restriction. As you should know in RDF anyone can say anything about everything. That means that one person can decide that the range also includes doubles and then this will be true as well.

If you are looking at some kind of sanity check then you will have to do this outside rdf (or use an inferences to spot inconsistencies).

Comment: That's it! Can you change owl:DatatypeProperty to rdf:Property ? I'm using XML/RDF.

Answer (score 0):

To specifically answer your question, you use `xsd:int` as the value of the range assertion, as @JoshuaTaylor indicated.  But that does not mean what you think it means; `rdfs:range` doesn't restrict values of the property to the value specified in the range, nor does it 'forbid' values outside of the stated range.

Range is used to *infer* information about the value of the property.  For example, you can say the range of some property `p` is both `A` and `B`.  Then if you have an assertion of the form `:s :p :o` a reasoner which knows about range will infer that `o` is both an `A` and a `B`.  There is nothing to prevent you from also asserting that `o` is a `C` (`:o a :C`), this just means that, when combined with the previous assertion, that `o` is an `A`, `B`, and `C`.

You can't really use RDFS, or OWL, for validation, at least not out of the box.  There's been work in this area, and recently a [workshop](http://www.w3.org/2012/12/rdf-val/) to look at how some vendors are supporting validation and see what might be a reasonable approach for standardizing.

Comment: So why bother having those types if they can't actually give some form of validation? If something is meant to be integer but goes wild (string notation etc) then what happens?

Comment: @user2692669 There are a few reasons. In OWL, a reasoner can detect an inconsistency for datatype properties.  For object properties, this can be used to infer additional information about individuals.  E.g., if the range of ownsHouse is House, then from Bill ownsHouse 72RoxburyStreet we can _infer_ that 72RoxburyStreet is a House, even if wasn't explicitly so inferred.  1 and 2 actually related;  if 72RoxburyStreet had previously been declared (or inferred) to have some type that's disjoint from House, we'd get an inconsistency, so there is a kind of validation.  Specifying domain and range…

Comment: @user269266 …is also a way of telling other _people_ "_this_ is what this property means, and how it should be used".

Comment: Nothing really happens when you assert a valid for a property outside of its declared range.  If you're using a reasoner, as Joshua pointed out, it will affect what's inferred, but there will not be any alarms or failures.  If you want validation for RDF, you have to create a homegrown custom solution, or use someone else's.

Comment: I try to use <rdfs:range rdf:int/> but this FatalError comes up: FatalError: Attribute name "rdf:int" associated with an element type "rdfs:range" must be followed by the ' = ' character.